# Get last ID number from table

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I tried this:

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table"; 
$result=sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
$values = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
var_dump($values);
echo $values;
?>
```

But I got this on my webpage:

C:\wamp64\www\site\site.php:18:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => int 1
  '' => int 1
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: do you have rows in `ID` column

Comment: Is your `ID` column an `IDENTITY`? Sure you're looking for `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: Yes, you are missing that the behavior of `sqlsrv_fetch_array` is _documented_ in the manual, so you can go and read up on what it does. https://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php The default value for the second parameter `$fetchType` is `SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH` - which means you will get each value under a numeric key _and_ and associative one. (The associative key is an empty string here, because the pseudo–“column” you are fetching does not have an alias.) So specify either `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` or `SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC`, depending on which you actually want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$values` is an array, so you need to access the direct value if you want to echo it. The max ID is 1, as shown by your `var_dump()` - but you get two results from the array `$values`, one associative and one numeric indexed. If you alias your data from the query, you can then fetch the associative value by name of that alias.

```php
<?php 
$query = "SELECT MAX(ID) as maxID FROM Table"; 
$result=sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
$values = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
echo $values['maxID'];
```

Or if you want to access it numerically,

```php
<?php 
$query = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table"; 
$result=sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
$values = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
echo $values[0];
```

Comment: I won't use `MAX()` as it may return the wrong `ID`.

Comment: I read the question as "*why am I getting the result I got*", and sort of missed the title in the big letters above. You're right, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` would return the correct result, but there's no function to return that from the PHP `sqlsrv_` functions directly (not that I'm aware of anyways).